# VirtualBox: trouble creating vmdk file-access denied

Tags: mac, virtualbox

I am brand new to VirtualBox.  I am trying to run a DOS iso image using VirtualBox 5.2.22 on an iMac and connect it to my Mac hard drive /Dev/Disk1.

I created the VM in VirtualBox with a DOS OS, added an IDE controller connected to the ISO file in the storage tab.  The VirtualBox folder for the VM named SpinRite is: Users/RainerOtto/VirtualBox/SpinRite

I am running this on an account (RainerOtto) with administrator rights.

I changed the ownership of the disk from root to my account:

> sudo chown RainerOtto /dev/disk1

I checked that this worked using: `ls -l /dev/disk1`

> brw-r-----  1 RainerOtto  operator    1,   3 Nov 16 11:45 /dev/disk1

I think this means that the account RainerOtto owns /dev/disk1 with read/write access.

Then I tried to create the vmdk file using:

> VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename
>   /Users/RainerOtto/VirtualBox/SpinRite/raw-disk0.vmdk
>   -rawdisk/dev/disk1

I get the error message:

> VBoxManage: error: Cannot open the raw disk '/dev/disk1':
>   VERR_ACCESS_DENIED VBoxManage: error: The raw disk vmdk file was not
>   created

How can I solve the access denied error?  Any assistance is sincerely appreciated.

Below is the listing of the VBoxManage Systemproperties

```
API version:                     5_2
Minimum guest RAM size:          4 Megabytes
Maximum guest RAM size:          2097152 Megabytes
Minimum video RAM size:          0 Megabytes
Maximum video RAM size:          256 Megabytes
Maximum guest monitor count:     64
Minimum guest CPU count:         1
Maximum guest CPU count:         32
Virtual disk limit (info):       2199022206976 Bytes
Maximum Serial Port count:       4
Maximum Parallel Port count:     2
Maximum Boot Position:           4
Maximum PIIX3 Network Adapter count:   8
Maximum ICH9 Network Adapter count:   36
Maximum PIIX3 IDE Controllers:   1
Maximum ICH9 IDE Controllers:    1
Maximum IDE Port count:          2
Maximum Devices per IDE Port:    2
Maximum PIIX3 SATA Controllers:  1
Maximum ICH9 SATA Controllers:   8
Maximum SATA Port count:         30
Maximum Devices per SATA Port:   1
Maximum PIIX3 SCSI Controllers:  1
Maximum ICH9 SCSI Controllers:   8
Maximum SCSI Port count:         16
Maximum Devices per SCSI Port:   1
Maximum SAS PIIX3 Controllers:   1
Maximum SAS ICH9 Controllers:    8
Maximum SAS Port count:          255
Maximum Devices per SAS Port:    1
Maximum NVMe PIIX3 Controllers:  1
Maximum NVMe ICH9 Controllers:   8
Maximum NVMe Port count:         255
Maximum Devices per NVMe Port:   1
Maximum PIIX3 Floppy Controllers:1
Maximum ICH9 Floppy Controllers: 1
Maximum Floppy Port count:       1
Maximum Devices per Floppy Port: 2
Default machine folder:          /Users/rainerotto2/VirtualBox
Raw-mode Supported:              no
Exclusive HW virtualization use: off
Default hard disk format:        VDI
VRDE auth library:               VBoxAuth
Webservice auth. library:        VBoxAuth
Remote desktop ExtPack:          
Log history count:               3
Default frontend:                
Default audio driver:            CoreAudio
Autostart database path:         
Default Guest Additions ISO:     /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
Logging Level:                   all
```

Below are file permissions to the files in /Users/RainerOtto/VirtualBox/Spinrite/

```
iMac-321:/ RainerOtto$ ls -l /users/rainerotto/virtualbox/spinrite total 3008
-rw-r--r--  1 RainerOtto  staff  1529856 Nov 16 11:56 SpinRite.iso
-rw-------  1 RainerOtto  staff     2076 Nov 16 18:32 SpinRite.vbox
-rw-------  1 RainerOtto  staff     2076 Nov 16 12:49 SpinRite.vbox-prev
```

I tried to change the folder permissions to drwxr-x---.  Even though the chmod 750 /folder command executed without error the folder permissions did not change.

```
iMac-321:~ rainerotto$ chmod 750 /users/rainerotto/virtualbox/spinrite 
iMac-321:~ rainerotto$ ls -l /users/rainerotto/virtualbox/spinrite 
total 3008 
-rw-r--r-- 1 rainerotto staff 1529856 Nov 16 11:56 SpinRite.iso 
-rw------- 1 rainerotto staff 2119 Nov 16 22:01 SpinRite.vbox 
-rw------- 1 rainerotto staff 2119 Nov 16 22:01 SpinRite.vbox-prev
```

Comment: Have you tried running VBoxManage as root?  Provide the relevant information, from `VBoxManage list systemproperties`, the information is required to answer your question.  You should edit your question, not submit the information in a comment, be sure to format the information so it can be easily be read.

Comment: I ran `VBoxManage list systemproperties` and looked through the output.  What attribute am I looking for?  I ran `VBoxManage` as root and received the same error message.

Comment: Just provide the information.....Otherwise I cannot help you

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your assistance.  I added the VBoxManage systemproperties to the bottom of the problem description.

Comment: Why is the default folder “rainerotto2” if your username is “rainerotto”? Is that intentional?  Does your user have the appropriate permissions to the default folder? Provide the current permissions on the root directory of the default directory and the default directory itself as an edit to your question

Comment: @Ramhound  I've posted the file permissions, as requested.  I tried to execute VBoxManage from two different accounts: RainerOtto and RainerOtto2.  They both have the same error.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I was looking for */Users/rainerotto2/VirtualBox* also.  You should also try changing the permissions to 750.

Comment: @Ramhound: I tried changing permissions of the folder to drwxr-x--- using chmod 750 /folder. Even though the command did not give an error the file permissions did not change.  I've posted the details to the bottom of the question.